# Can a VM be displayed on a monitor that is not used by the host?

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, virtualization

I am using VirtualBox to virtualize an Ubuntu VM on a Windows host.

I have 3 monitors but the host can only use 2 of them at the same time. However, it recognizes the third monitor.

Can a VM be displayed on that third monitor? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The VM is limited to what the host can do. If the 3rd monitor is not working for the host, the VM cannot be displayed on it either.

VirtualBox has no control over the monitor from a hardware point of view, so you rely on other hardware to drive that monitor.

It is possible though, to use a 2nd pc, connect the monitor to that pc, and start your VM in headless mode and connect to it using Remote Desktop. You need the VirtualBox extension package to allow the RDP server though.

Of course this does mean that if you also want to control it, you will need a second keyboard/mouse, or interact to it from your current computer. It is possible to make 2 RDP sessions to that VM simultaniously, so your screen can still kept viewing it while you temporarily connect to the VM from your own pc to interact with it.